# How to convert 4 vales of modbus registers (each 16 bit) to a double float in C?

Tags: c, converters

How to convert 4 vales of modbus registers (each 16 bit) to a double float in C?
That's my problem. How can i solve this in C?

Comment: Please be more specific. Show what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: What is the significance of the four 16-bit values?  How are they related to the desired floating-point value?